# IBM DB2 Select named column, then select *

Tags: sql, db2

I can't seem to figure out how to do the following in an IBM DB2 select statement:

```
SELECT column1, *
FROM [some table]
```

I get the following error:

```
SELECT ACCT_NUM, * FROM GEG1.RENL_RATING_STRUC
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "*" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "+ - ROW NEXTVAL PREVVAL NEXT PREVIOUS ( <INTEGER> <DECIMAL>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

I searched for a syntax document, but I couldn't find one. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Do note that when you do this you'll have two columns in the result set with the same name, and that could create other problems.

Comment: Good point @GordonLinoff...this is something you'd only want to do as a shortcut when interacting looking at the data.  In general production code should never have SELECT *.

Comment: I'm only using it for developing a query. The asterisk will be removed before production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give the table an alias, you can prefix the asterisk with the alias to do what you want:

```
SELECT A.id, A.*
FROM your_table A
```

You have to interpret the `select-clause` definition from [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000875.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F5-5-5-1&lang=en):

```
           .-ALL------.   
>>-SELECT--+----------+----------------------------------------->
           '-DISTINCT-'   

>--+-*-----------------------------------------------+---------><
   | .-,-------------------------------------------. |   
   | V                                             | |   
   '---+-expression--+-------------------------+-+-+-'   
       |             | .-AS-.                  | |       
       |             '-+----+--new-column-name-' |       
       '-exposed-name.*--------------------------'
```

So, this basically reads "you can `SELECT *` **OR** you can select multiple expressions (a column) or `exposed-name.*`, separated by a comma".

Comment: I doing RENL_RATNG_STRUC.*, but that didn't work. It never occured to me to alias the table itself. Thanks!

Comment: @DanChampagne if you found my answer helpful, you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to the vote buttons!

Comment: @DanChampagne your method would probably work if you included the schema for the table as well:  `SELECT column1, GEG1.RENL_RATING_STRUC.* FROM [some table]`